# Scan a Matrix for a number

Tags: java, matrix

I am currently looking for a way of scanning a 2D matrix in Java for a number. Precisely, if in my matrix, there are numbers from 0 to 9, how do I "locate" the 0? This is intended for creating a Minesweeper game.

Here is what I have written so far. It is not complete. All I want is a clue on how to complete it.

```
class DemineurStackOverflow {

  public static void minesweeper () {

    int champDeMine[][];
    boolean résultat[][];
    int mine;
    char réponse;

    champDeMine = new int[longueur][largeur]; //Differenf from the matrix "champDeMines" from the second method
    Arrays.asList(champDeMine).contains(0);
    mine = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*nbMines + 1);
    System.out.println("Ajustement du nombre de mines en cours...");
    if (mine < nbMines) {
      for (mine = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*nbMines + 1); mine < nbMines; mine++);
    } else {
      for (mine = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*nbMines + 1); mine > nbMines; mine--);
    }

    if (mine == nbMines){
      System.out.println("Chargement des mines OK.");
    }
  }

  public static int [][] calculeProximité ( boolean [][] champDeMines ){
    int row; //row index for prescence of 0, same value as longueur
    int col; //column index for presence of 0, same value as largeur
    int mine;

    champDeMines = new boolean[row][col];
    if (champDeMines = 0) {
      champDeMines = mine;
    }

    //Here I am trying to figure a way of finding the 0s in this champDeMines matrix.

    return (new int[champDeMines.length][champDeMines[0].length]);
  }
}
```

The first method consists in generating an array from variables "longueur" and "largeur". The number of "mines" is supposed to represent the number 0 (which is why I want to scan for a 0), at random places. The second method consists in finding the "mines" in the array created. That is what I have trouble doing. Do you have any ***clues*** for completing the second method? I am simply looking for clues because I am learning to program in Java!

Thank you very much, your help is most certainly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how minesweeper field population could look from the code provided. I hope you get the clue from the comments and do not hesitate to ask if anything is unclear.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Demineur 
{
    // Here come CONSTANTS
    public static final int     MAX_MINES = 30;
    public static final boolean MINE      = true;

    // Let's have a field 12x12 size
    public static final int LONGEUR   = 12;
    public static final int LARGEUR   = 12;

    // each field contains number of mines it has access to
    public static int     champDeMine[][]  = new int[LONGEUR][LARGEUR];

    // each field can contain mine or be empty
    public static boolean champDeMines[][] = new boolean[LONGEUR][LARGEUR];

    public static void minesweeper() 
    {
        Random  random  = new Random();
        int     mine           ;

        System.out.println("Ajustement du nombre de mines en cours...");
        int     nbMines = random.nextInt(MAX_MINES);

        /**
         * Let's plant mines. :-E
         * Unoptimal but will suffice for demonstration purpose.
         */
        int minesLeftToPlant = nbMines;
        int skip             = 0;
        boolean planted      = false;
        while (minesLeftToPlant > 0)
        {
            skip    = random.nextInt(LONGEUR*LARGEUR);
            planted = false;
            while (!planted && minesLeftToPlant > 0 && skip > 0)
            {
                for (int y = 0; !planted && minesLeftToPlant > 0 && y < LONGEUR; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; !planted && minesLeftToPlant > 0 && x < LARGEUR; x++)
                    {
                        if (   !MINE == champDeMines[y][x] 
                            && 0 == skip)
                        {
                            champDeMines[y][x] = MINE;
                            minesLeftToPlant--;
                            planted = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            skip--;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Chargement des "+ nbMines +" mines OK.");
    }

    public static void calculeProximite()
    {
        int row ; //row index for prescence of 0, same value as longueur
        int col ; //column index for presence of 0, same value as largeur
        int mine;

        //Check for each field it's neighbors and calculate which of them are mines
        for (row = 0; row < LONGEUR; row++)
        {
            for (col = 0; col < LARGEUR; col++)
            {
                champDeMine[row][col] = numberOfMines(row,col);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void printChampDeMine()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < LONGEUR; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < LARGEUR; col++)
            {
                System.out.print("'" + champDeMine[row][col] + "' ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void printChampDemines()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < LONGEUR; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < LARGEUR; col++)
            {
                System.out.print("'" + (champDeMines[row][col] ? "m" : "e") + "' ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int numberOfMines(int row, int col)
    {
        return add(hasMine(row    , col + 1))
            +  add(hasMine(row - 1, col + 1))
            +  add(hasMine(row - 1, col    ))
            +  add(hasMine(row - 1, col - 1))
            +  add(hasMine(row    , col - 1))
            +  add(hasMine(row + 1, col - 1))
            +  add(hasMine(row + 1, col    ))
            +  add(hasMine(row + 1, col + 1));
    }

    public static boolean hasMine(int row, int col)
    {
        return row >= 0 && col >= 0 && row < LONGEUR && col < LARGEUR 
            && isMine(champDeMines[row][col]);
    }

    public static boolean isMine(boolean x)
    {
        return MINE == x;
    }

    public static int add(boolean c)
    {
        return c ? 1 : 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        minesweeper();
        System.out.println("Champ de mines");
        printChampDemines();
        System.out.println("Champ de mine");
        calculeProximite();
        printChampDeMine();
    }
}
```